# How to send a graphql query that has no subquery and no field using apollo client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I sent a request using apollo-client's gql and useQuery .

- API Demo Url: http://practice.codebootcamp.co.kr/graphql

I used the query is `fetchBoardsCount`, and the information is on the below.

```
// docs
fetchBoardsCount: Int!

// query
query {
  fetchBoardsCount
}
```

The query worked on API Demo, so I sent on client (Next.js).But it is not working.

```
// query
export const FETCH_BOARDS_COUNT = gql`{
    query FetchBoardsCount {
        fetchBoardsCount
    }
}`;

// request query
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(FETCH_BOARDS_COUNT);
```

This is the response.

```
Cannot query field \"query\" on type \"Query\".
```

**How to send grqphql query that no subquery, no field using apollo-client?**

#### package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.21",
    "eslint": "8.25.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
export const FETCH_BOARDS_COUNT = gql` 
    query{
        fetchBoardsCount
    }`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not working also.

Comment: what's the error

Comment: Same error. `Cannot query field \"query\" on type \"Query\".`

Comment: what is the client you are using

Comment: I use Next.js. I append my package.json to the answer.